# How can I start an another GUI from virtual console in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, xorg, gui

After switching with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> to another virtual console what are the steps to start the same GUI as usual with the same or another user?

The only progress I've achieved is an X session (?) after `sudo startx` command.

Answer (score 0):

Under KDE there is in main menu "start session under different user" entry. You do not need to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f[n]</kbd>. If you are using KDE.